# R - Make the ratio of two variables in column C, based on two levels in colum B, by gruping of column A

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

As title, trying to make the ratio of two variables in a column based on their grouping in two other columns.

```
colA colB colC
a1   b_1  24
a1   b_2  26
a2   b_1  12
a2   b_2  14
a3   b_1  19
a3   b_2  21
```

what i need is a new column with the ratio between b_1/b_2, grouped by colA

```
   colA colB colC  colD
    a1   b_1  24   26/24
    a1   b_2  26    
    a2   b_1  12   14/12
    a2   b_2  14   
    a3   b_1  19   21/19
    a3   b_2  21
```

i am trying with dplyr but i still can not do it

```
df %>% select(colA, colB, colC) %>%
   group_by(colA,colB) %>%
   mutate(ratio,  ???????
```

Additionally I need to do a ratio of colC values for a1_b_1,colC dividing all the other a*_b_1,colC, same for a1_b2_colC dividing all the other a*_b_2_colC

```
   colA colB colC  colD
    a1   b_1  24   
    a1   b_2  26    
    a2   b_1  12  
    a2   b_2  14   
    a3   b_1  19   
    a3   b_2  21
```

Comment: Can you clarify the last part of the question? What is the desired result with this example? What is the denominator in that division? `sum(colC[colB == b_1])`?

Comment: Could you please add your data as `data.frame()` in the question? So information can simply be copied to test solutions.

Comment: I am trying to obtain a colD, where every value in colB == b_1 is divided by the colC value of colA == a1. Basically the first two rows will be the denominators of every value in colC in the two groups defined by colB. In the example, colD will give colD= 1, 1, 12/24,14/26,19/24,21/26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a tibble `df`, which you can get by calling `dput`,

```
df = tibble::tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB, ~colC,
   "a1","b_1", 24,
   "a1","b_2", 26,
   "a2","b_1", 12,
   "a2","b_2", 14,
   "a3","b_1", 19,
   "a3","b_2", 21)
```

We can follow the logic as used in the question:

```
df %>%
  group_by(colA) %>%
  mutate(ColD = c(colC[2] / colC[1], NA)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  colA  colB   colC  ColD
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a1    b_1      24  1.08
2 a1    b_2      26 NA   
3 a2    b_1      12  1.17
4 a2    b_2      14 NA   
5 a3    b_1      19  1.11
6 a3    b_2      21 NA
```

Comment: About the additional question, do you have any insight? I would try to do    group_by(colB) %>% mutate(colD = c(colC/colC...) ?????? Here I should put something like colC ~ colA[a1]? I tried but it does not work..

Comment: @lucad8 not sure what you are trying to do. `24 / (26 + 12 + 14 + ...)` ?

Comment: I am trying to obtain a colD, where every value in colB == b_1 is divided by the colC value of colA == a1. Basically the first two rows will be the denominators of every value in colC in the two groups defined by colB. In the example, colD will give colD= 1, 1, 12/24,14/26,19/24,21/26

Comment: @lucad8 you could define `n = 24` and `m = 26`, then use the same logic as before. `df %>% group_by(colA) %>% mutate(colD = c(colC[1]/n, colC[2]/m))`

Answer (score 0):

Using **base R**, this one-liner will give you the ratios.

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$colA), function(x) cbind(x, colD = x[2, 'colC'] / x[1, 'colC'])))
```

**Output**

```
> df
     colA colB colC     colD
a1.1   a1  b_1   24 1.083333
a1.2   a1  b_2   26 1.083333
a2.3   a2  b_1   12 1.166667
a2.4   a2  b_2   14 1.166667
a3.5   a3  b_1   19 1.105263
a3.6   a3  b_2   21 1.105263
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  colA = rep(paste0('a', 1:3), each = 2L),
  colB = rep(paste0('b_', 1:2), 3L),
  colC = c(24,26,12,14,19,21)
)
```